# I want to fix the marker in the center of the map ios

Tags: swift, dictionary, marker

I want to fix the marker in the center of the google map in **Swift**
and I do not want to use CMSCircle
i want to fix the marker in the center
and move map and marker not change place

Answer (score 1):

You can add this extension to your view controller .The marker will move to the centre every time you move the map

```
extension MyMapViewController: GMSMapViewDelegate{
    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, idleAt position: GMSCameraPosition) {
        marker.position = position.target
        reverseGeocodeCoordinate(coordinate: position.target)
    }
}
```